# Unable to run Maven project from Eclipse due to error - I'm new to Maven

Tags: java, maven, twilio

I am trying to test the Twilio API, and I am having issues running the application within eclipse (neon) as a maven project; but as just a simple Java application.

When I create this project as an eclipse project it works (I import the required jar files directly) and I can execute the project from within eclipse by selecting Run As...java Application.

So what am I missing?  I did the build.  I also get an error when I try to execute.

Here is the source cold I used in both the projects.  Please excuse my choice of class name.

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

public class OkFuckingWork
{
  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  private static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "xxxxxxx";
  private static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxx";
  private static String to = "1xxxxx";
  private static String from = "1xxxxx";

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(to),
        new PhoneNumber(from), 
        "OK This works.").create();

    //System.out.println(message.getSid());
  }
}
```

The jar file I am using in my regular project is twilio-7.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

The maven pom file is as follows.
[image]

Now, if I try and run this program from within eclipse, I get the following error.

[image]

As you can see here, it looks like I have all my dependencies....so what gives?

[image]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>thirdgear</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyTwilioTestCase</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
          <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
          <version>(7.0,7.9)</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here is the stack trace i get when I run this project

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException
    at OkFuckingWork.main(OkFuckingWork.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more

I build using Run As -> Maven generate sources and the project compiles and produces my class file.

To run, (I have specified my main class) I select Run As -> Java Application.  This is when I get the above stack trace.

Comment: Post your code and your error as text. Not as images. They're unreadable, and that makes it impossible to copy, paste and edit. And please choose a better title for your question.

Comment: every time i copy my code into the editor i get nothing but headaches with the formatting.  I will try again with the pom.xml file

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>thirdgear</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyTwilioTestCase</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <dependencies>
  
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
    <version>(7.0,7.9)</version>
 </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 
</project>

Comment: Don't post the in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @JB Nizer, what would you recommend as a better title?

Comment: Can you share your directory structure ?

Comment: Something that describes your question. Something like "Unable to run Maven project from Eclipse due to error <unreadable>"

Comment: @JB Nizet, done

Comment: Other than pasting a .png to the post, how else can i display my directory structure?

Comment: That's OK. But post the exception stack trace. And tell us how you run the program. Tell us if it at least compiles fine.

Comment: Please see my updates at the bottom of my post.